# Capitalizing and changing font/color in Label Expression using Python Parser of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, python-parser

Currently Using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.2 and Python.

I am currently trying to label Road names, which are all uppercase in the database. I'm unable to edit the database but would like to Capitalize the road names and pick out one street to change the font and color for the road name.

I'm new to python and am having trouble working out how to combine these two expressions.

```
def FindLabel ( [road_name1] ):
  S = [road_name1]
  S = S.title()
  return S

def FindLabel ( [road_name1] ):
  if str([road_name1]) == 'LOOKOUT ROAD':
    return "<CLR red='0' blue='0' green='0'><FNT size = '22'>" + [road_name1] + "</FNT></CLR>"
  else:
    return "<CLR red='128' blue='128' green='128'><FNT size = '14'>" + [road_name1] + "</FNT></CLR>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to create one function instead of two functions and put the `S.title()` inside the font change function like this:

```
def FindLabel ( [road_name1] ):
    S = [road_name1]
    if S == 'LOOKOUT ROAD':
        return "<CLR red='0' blue='0' green='0'><FNT size = '22'>" + S.title() + "</FNT></CLR>"
    else:
        return "<CLR red='128' blue='128' green='128'><FNT size = '14'>" + S.title() + "</FNT></CLR>"
```